# Помогите с кодом пожалуста

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Нужна помощь с кодом, в чем моя ошибка. Добра вам)

```js
let cars = [
    {
        name: 'Aston-Martin DB9',
        color: 'Grey',
        country: 'UK',
        price: 350000,
    },
    
    {
        name: 'Mercedes CLK GTR',
        color: 'Grey',
        country: 'Germany',
        price: 1500000,
    },

    {
        name: 'Ford GT',
        color: 'Red',
        country: 'USA',
        price: 500000,
    },
];

function getElementsOfTask18Array (arrayElement,tag) {
    let block = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)

    for (let i = 0 ; i < arrayElement.length; i++) {
        let part = arrayElement[i];
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        let name = document.createElement('h3');
        let color = document.createElement('h4');
        let country = document.createElement('h5');
        let price = document.createElement('h6');

        name.innerHTML = `${part.name}`;
        color.innerHTML = `${part.color}`;
        country.innerHTML = `${part.country}`;
        price.innerHTML = `${part.price}`;

        div.appendChild(name);
        div.appendChild(color);
        div.appendChild(country);
        div.appendChild(price);

        block.appendChild(div);
    }
}
getElementsOfTask18Array(cars);
```

Comment: В в м проблема что хотелось получить?

Comment: К примеру я вижу ошибку тут. let block = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)

Comment: Вы получили список. А обращаетесь как с элементом

Comment: block.appendChild(div);

Comment: Нужно разные ключи объектов разместить по разным элементам

Comment: Что и как мне нужно изменить?

Comment: getElementsOfTask18Array(cars, "body");

Comment: block[0].appendChild(div);

Comment: Большое спасибо. Последний вопрос, почему я должен был прописать " body " и возле block [0] ??? Оно что-то дает?

Comment: У вас добавляется элементы в тег. А боди есть у всех.

Comment: А зачем createElement??? Формируйте сразу строку и её вставляйте в блок, код в три раза короче и быстрее. createElement полезен, если необходимо далее вешать обработки, у вас просто табличка на экране.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, а можно эдак:

```js
let cars = [
    {
        name: 'Aston-Martin DB9',
        color: 'Grey',
        country: 'UK',
        price: 350000,
    },
    
    {
        name: 'Mercedes CLK GTR',
        color: 'Grey',
        country: 'Germany',
        price: 1500000,
    },

    {
        name: 'Ford GT',
        color: 'Red',
        country: 'USA',
        price: 500000,
    },
];

function getElementsOfTask18Array (arr,tag,tag2) {
    let block = document.querySelector(tag);
    let block2 = document.querySelector(tag2);
    let res = '';
    let res2 = '';
    for(let ind in arr) {
        res += '<div>';
        for(let key in arr[ind]) {
            if (key=='name') res += '<h3>'+ arr[ind][key] +'</h3>';
            if (key=='color') res += '<h4>'+ arr[ind][key] +'</h4>';
            if (key=='country') res += '<h5>'+ arr[ind][key] +'</h5>';
            if (key=='price') res += '<h6>'+ arr[ind][key] +'</h6>';
        }
        res += '</div>';
    }
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    for (let ind in arr) {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (let elem in arr[ind]) {
            let td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = arr[ind][elem];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    block.innerHTML = res;
    block2.appendChild(table);
}
getElementsOfTask18Array(cars,'.res','.res2');
```

```css
h3,h4,h5,h6{margin:2px 0}
h3 {font-size: 26px;}
h4 {font-size: 22px;}
h5 {font-size: 18px;}
h6 {font-size: 14px;}
p{color: blueviolet;margin: 10px 0;}
.result > div {border: 1px solid magenta;padding: 10px;margin: 10px 0;}
table {width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;}
td {padding: 8px 16px;border: 1px solid gold;}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p>1 вариант</p>
    <div class="result res"></div>
    <p>2 вариант</p>
    <div class="result res2"></div>
</div>
```